# Problem login screen with swiftUi navigate to ViewController

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-environment

I created a login screen using SwiftUI.
When I press a login button (after the validation of email and password), it navigates to a ViewController.

Login state is stored in a `userDefault` Boolean for use later when the app is launched again.
In `SceneDelegate`, `userDefault` is checked--if it is`true`, the main screen is shown; otherwise the login screen is shown.

In a View Controller I created a `itemBar` Logout button which navigates back to the login screen when it is pressed.

I managed to implement the above logic.
The problem happens when I successfully log in then close the app in a simulator and open again.
When I press the Logout Bar item, the app isn't responsive and does not navigate back to the Login screen.

I tried to use the Coordinator pattern without success. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi Liram. It's difficult to read and understand your story. Could you describe in bullet points what you mean?

Comment: It would be easier to figure out the problem if a working example that demonstrates your problem is provided.